# Precision is lost when doing cast of double value to decimal in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to retrieve a field value which is of type double in SQL Server and then casting it to decimal with scaling factor 13 and 14. If the scale is 13, it is giving proper result. If the scale is 14, the value is getting changed.

I am using the below queries and their respective results.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(discount AS DECIMAL(30,13)) as real_value,
    discount 
FROM pricetable 
WHERE ref = '123'
```

Result: (Decimal('123.9900000000000'), 123.99)

Query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(pricepaid AS DECIMAL(30, 14)) as real_value,
    pricepaid 
FROM pricetable 
WHERE ref = '123'
```

Result:(Decimal('115.84999999999999'), 115.85)

Why does casting double to decimal with different scaling factors produce different results? Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: You're query doesn't really make a alot of sense here, as your "results" don't actually show what your result is. `SELECT CONVERT(decimal(30,13), 123.9900000000000);` returns `123.9900000000000`, which is correct. You need to provide sample data so that we can replicate your issue. `SELECT CONVERT(decimal(30,13), 123.9900000000000);` will never return the value `'(Decimal('123.9900000000000'), 123.99)'` as that is a `varchar`.

Comment: In the first query, you can see I am retrieving discount value from the pricetable which is 123.99 and converting it to decimal with a scale of 13 and the result is Decimal('123.9900000000000'). In the second query, I am retrieving pricepaid value which is 115.85 and converting it to decimal with a scale of 14 and the result is Decimal('115.84999999999999'). discount and pricepaid values are stored as double in sql server tables.

Answer (score 0):

Doubles always are approximations. **Best Just Use DECIMAL.** But you could multiply by powers of 10, and round etcetera.

---

It is a matter of rounding, how more digits the more the error comes to bear in the rounding. 0.11585x10³ has in base 2 an infinite number of digits theoretically. 10^-(13+3) is about 2^-52, and a double has 52 mantissa bits, so with a scale of 14 the physical limit is reached too.

But mind, a *double* that is displayed as 115.85 will when multiplied by a large number also multiply the approximation error, like 115.85 * 1000 = 11584.9999

Comment: Joop, I want to know by why the value is changed after changing the scale from 13 to 14.

Comment: It is giving correct result if I a give a scale in between 1 to 13. The value is changing if the scale is more than 13.